# Short jumps with a relative offset not using the offset I expect

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to understand the short jmp instruction. I have a very simple program, compiled with nasm:

```
        SECTION .data
bsh:    db "/bin/sh",0
arr:    dq bsh,0

        SECTION .text
        global main
main:
        jmp    short 0x20
        mov    edx, 0
        mov    rsi, arr
        mov    rdi, bsh
        mov    rax, 0x3b
        syscall

        mov    ebx, 0
        mov    eax, 0x3c
        syscall
```

Disassembled, the code looks like this in gdb (disassemble main):

```
0x00000000004000b0 <+0>:      jmp    0x4000d1 <main+33>
0x00000000004000b2 <+2>:      mov    $0x0,%edx
0x00000000004000b7 <+7>:      movabs $0x6000e8,%rsi
0x00000000004000c1 <+17>:     movabs $0x6000e0,%rdi
0x00000000004000cb <+27>:     mov    $0x3b,%eax
0x00000000004000d0 <+32>:     syscall
0x00000000004000d2 <+34>:     mov    $0x0,%ebx
0x00000000004000d7 <+39>:     mov    $0x3c,%eax
0x00000000004000dc <+44>:     syscall
```

I'm trying to jump to `0x4000d2`. 34 - 2 = 32 = 0x20. 0x4000d2 - 0x4000b2 = 0x20. No matter what I assemble, nasm always seems to code the jump address as an offset from one byte past the start of the jump instruction. Why is `jmp short 0x20` assembling wrong? (not to mention that `jmp 0x20` had a different result, and was a 5 byte instruction instead of a 2 byte instruction)

I'm also reading about [smashing the stack for fun and profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html). Aleph1 wants to jump from jmp to call and then from call to popl. This is the code he uses:

```
jmp    0x26                 # 2 bytes
popl   %esi                 # 1 byte
movl   %esi,0x8(%esi)       # 3 bytes
movb   $0x0,0x7(%esi)       # 4 bytes
movl   $0x0,0xc(%esi)       # 7 bytes
movl   $0xb,%eax            # 5 bytes
movl   %esi,%ebx            # 2 bytes
leal   0x8(%esi),%ecx       # 3 bytes
leal   0xc(%esi),%edx       # 3 bytes
int    $0x80                # 2 bytes
movl   $0x1, %eax           # 5 bytes
movl   $0x0, %ebx           # 5 bytes
int    $0x80                # 2 bytes
call   -0x2b                # 5 bytes
.string \"/bin/sh\"         # 8 bytes
```

Adding up the bytes from `popl %esi` to `call -0x2b` I get 42. Shouldn't the first instruction then be `jmp 0x2a`? And subtracting bytes from the end of the call instruction to the beginning of `popl %esi` I get -47. Shouldn't the call be `call -0x2f`? When he actually creates a c file and puts his assembly in an `__asm__` block, he uses the offsets I calculated, but not in this code which is before that. What changed?

And while I'm here, couldn't he have just accessed eip and used that to get the relative offset of the string in memory?

Comment: It looks like you got the answer, but just to reiterate, in assembly you jump or branch to labels only. The problem is that there is really no way to know how big a piece of code is going to be unless you write it in hexadecimal directly, which would be a really big waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Intel syntax, this should be:

```
jmp     short $+022h    ;jump from current location ($ == 4000b0) to 4000d2
```

Note that a long jump using the same $+022h syntax would still end up jumping to 4000d2, as the assembler would generate a smaller offset field. This type of usage is rare, with the most common exception being jmp short $+2 used in legacy code to generate very short delays between I/O device accesses.

Comment: This encodes `EB 1E`, which is a jump to the interrupt. `jmp short 0x20` encodes `EB 1F`. (I checked the assembly with gdb).

Comment: I'm not familiar with that assembler, but since PC = 4000b2 when the jump is executed, the offset from PC should be 0x1E to end up at 4000d0. The "$" represents the current location (as opposed to what PC will be when the instruction is executed), making the offset easier to calculate.

Comment: I'll upvote, though it's not quite what I'm looking for, so I can't accept it. What assembler do you use?

Comment: Alright, I went to the IRC channel, and they told me there's no way to use an offset like I want to with an assembler, so I'm going to accept this answer and leave this comment here for others. There are also labels as well.

Comment: +2 for the jump instruction?! As far as I know the offset is counted from after the jmp/call instructions.

Comment: > what assembler? - Microsoft MASM or ML, I assume Intel assembler syntax is also the same, "$" means current location.

Comment: > offset counted from after jump / call instruction - this is why the "$" is used for PC relative offset in assembly source code, since it's the current location, as opposed to the PC value after the jump / call instruction, which in the case of a jump, the assembler may change from a long jump to a short jump depending on the assembler.

Comment: > 4000d0 as target - I mis-read the original post and thought the goal was to branch to the syscall, at 4000d0, but the goal is to jump to 4000d2. Someone else corrected my answer, and I updated the comment to  explain how "$" is used.